# SpringData Avg NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data

i want to calculate an average from a column, but i am getting NPE.

With:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT avg(mood) FROM Mood WHERE date = :date")
Double getAvgMoodByDate(@Param("date")LocalDate date);
```

i'm getting:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.lang.Double
....
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```

Then i've created my own implementation of `@Repository`

```
public Double avgByDate(LocalDate date) {
  return (Double) entityManager.createQuery("SELECT avg(Mood.mood) FROM Mood WHERE Mood.date = :date")
          .setParameter("date", Date.valueOf(date))
          .getSingleResult();
}
```

this approach also lead to

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```

Could you please point me where i might be wrong.

Comment: Care to post the full stack trace? A `NullPointerException` is never healthy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem is when you are using `Mood.date`, so instead use an alias `FROM Mood m`, try also to use `coalesce` like this :

```
@Query(value = "SELECT coalesce(avg(m.mood), 0) FROM Mood m WHERE m.date = :date")
```

Comment: @Arashigor i think the real problem is when you use `Mood.date` instead you have to use an alias `...Mood m WHERE m.date...`